# Why no one seems to use FreeBSD to host Rails app?

Tags: unix, hosting, freebsd, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm moving this thread previous adressed to stackoverflow. ([Original Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071085/why-no-one-seems-to-use-freebsd-to-host-rails-app))

We use FreeBSD 8.2, Rails 3.0.7, postgresql 8.3, passenger and nginx for our production servers. ([More Infos](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/ports/www/rubygem-passenger/))

We seems to have a odd configuration because no one seems to have something like ours. I feel a little alone. ;-)

Nevertheless, this configuration is quite easy to setup, it performs well and it's very stable.

Is there a particular reason why Rails programmers seems to avoid FreeBSD as a production server ?

Comment: People use whatever platform they're most comfortable with. For various reasons there are more "Linux" people in the Ruby world than BSD people.  For what it's worth I run FreeBSD/Postgres/Passenger/Apache as a major part of my company's production web stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots and lots and LOTS of people use FreeBSD in Prod for their rails apps. Linux is also very popular because it's a little easier to get a fully-featured system up-and-running, especially if you aren't a Unix expert. BSD isn't that much harder, but it's hard enough to turn a lot of people off of the idea.

The advantages of FreeBSD are that it's a bit more stable and more secure fundamentally.